# ruby on rails: rspec not failing tests when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rspec

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      response.should be_success
    end
  end




end
```

Above is a very simple test I've written while learning the basics of testing in Ruby on rails, the problem is that it should be failing the "contact" test since I don't have this in my app/controllers/pages_controller.rb.

It return the following

```
   Finished in 0.04558 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

So it counts the test successfully but doesn't fail if one of them is wrong.

Comment: I assume the missing call to 'get' in that spec is just a typo. Do you already have a contact template (.erb, .haml etc. ) ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung which call specifically are you talking about?

Comment: And no, contact doesn't have any files/templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already the view files in contact, that's might be the reason to pass contact. Try to remove those files or rename the files and check again.

(or)

You might run into the same issues if you don't turn off caching in the test environment. Go to `config/environments/test.rb` and change `config.cache_classes = true` to `config.cache_classes = false`

It's might be the reason, if not let know.

Comment: @FRederickCheung was right, the tutorial had a typo which I didn't notice :/ thanks anyway